# k-means nstart equivalent for EM Clustering? Report only the best solution from a large number of initializations?

Tags: clustering, data-mining, k-means

In K-means clustering, you can specify an *nstart=i* parameter, which performs the algorithm *i* times (i.e. selects the initial *k* random centroids i times) sand reports the best answer only. If I perform this specifying nstart=10^6, then I get the same (presumably the best) results everytime I run kmeans for a given k.

However, in EM clustering, I am not sure which is the way to do this, if there is a way at all. I am using the EMCluster package in R, and when initializing the model for assigning clusters/classes, I am using the exhaust.EM function, with a `min.n.iter=10^9`. This still gives me a different answer everytime: some datapoints will belong to one cluster in one execution, and they will be excluded from that cluster the next.

Is there an equivalent to `nstart` from k-means for EM clustering?

Answer (score 0):

`nstart` for k-means doesn't guarantee the opimal result.

For k-means, you only have $O(k^n)$ different possible clustering solutions. This is large, but finite. Running an absurd amount of initialization is likely to eventually yield the best solution *reachable from your seeding stratgy* (which does *not* mean it is the globally optimal solution!)

EM clustering has an infinite amount of clustering solutions, on the magnitude of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times (k-1)}$. There is a lot of numerical parameter-tuning involved. So every different initialization will likely yield a slightly different solution when it reaches your stopping threshold (and you don't want until "true" converge, which is at infinite iterations).

Answer (score 0):

EM Gaussian clustering is different from k means in that you are optimizing a theoretical likelihood rather than simply calculating the distances between points. As such, starting positions do not matter so much (at least as far as I am aware). I have only used the `mclust` package for clustering so i don't know what `min.n.iter` does.